# TSQL Multiple count using same table with different JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, join

I have a weird situation and not too sure how to approach it.

I have 2 separate tables:

Table A is submissions

```
id
submitterQID
nomineeQID
story
```

Table B is employees

```
QID
Name
Department
```

I am trying to get the total number of submissions grouped by department as well as the total number of nominations.

This is what my Stored procedure looks like:

```
BEGIN
                SELECT   TOP 50 count(A.[nomineeQID]) AS totalNominations,
                                count(A.[subQID]) AS totalSubmissions,
                                B.[DepartmentDesc] AS department
                FROM     empowermentSubmissions AS A
                JOIN empTable AS B
                ON B.[qid] = A.[nomineeQID]
                WHERE A.[statusID] = 3
                AND A.[locationID] = @locale
                GROUP BY B.[Department]
                ORDER BY totalNominations DESC
                FOR      XML PATH ('data'), TYPE, ELEMENTS, ROOT ('root');
            END
```

This issue with this is that the JOIN is joining by the `nomineeQID` only and not the `subQID` as well.

My end result I am looking for is:

Department Customer Service has 25 submissions and 90 nominations

ORDERED BY the SUM of both counts...

I tried to just `JOIN` again on the `subQID` but was told I cant join on the same table twice.

Is there an easier way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a situaton where you'll need to gather your counts independently of each other. Using two left joins will cause some rows to be counted twice in the first left join when the join condition is met for both. Your scenario can be solved using either correlated subqueries or an outer apply gathering the counts on different criteria. I did not present a `COUNT(CASE ... )` option here, because you don't have an either-or scenario in the data, you have two foreign keys to the employees table. So, setting up sample data:

```
declare @empowermentSubmissions table (submissionID int primary key identity(1,1), submissionDate datetime, nomineeQID INT, submitterQID INT, statusID INT, locationID INT)
declare @empTable table (QID int primary key identity(1,1), AreaDesc varchar(10), DepartmentDesc varchar(20))
declare @locale INT = 0
declare @n int = 1

while @n < 50
begin
    insert into @empTable (AreaDesc, DepartmentDesc) values ('Area ' + cast((@n % 2)+1 as varchar(1)), 'Department ' + cast((@n % 4)+1 as varchar(1)))
    set @n = @n + 1
end
set @n = 1
while @n < 500
begin
    insert into @empowermentSubmissions (submissionDate, nomineeQID, submitterQID, StatusID, locationID) values (dateadd(dd,-(cast(rand()*600 as int)),getdate()), (select top 1 QID from @empTable order by newid()), (select top 1 QID from @empTable order by newid()), 3 + (@n % 2) - (@n % 3), (@n % 2) )
    set @n = @n + 1
end
```

And now the `OUTER APPLY` option:

```
SELECT TOP 50 E.DepartmentDesc, SUM(N.Nominations) Nominations, SUM(S.TotalSubmissions) TotalSubmissions
FROM @empTable E
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT COUNT(submissionID) Nominations
        FROM @empowermentSubmissions A
        WHERE A.statusID = 3
            AND A.nomineeQID = E.QID
            AND A.locationID = @locale
    ) N
    OUTER APPLY (
        SELECT COUNT(submissionID) TotalSubmissions
        FROM @empowermentSubmissions A
        WHERE A.statusID = 3
            AND A.submitterQID = E.QID
            AND A.locationID = @locale
    ) S
GROUP BY E.DepartmentDesc
ORDER BY SUM(Nominations) + SUM(TotalSubmissions) DESC
```

Comment: The one big question I have is performance on this. It seems like it is looking through the whole employeeTable and then when it finds something in the submissions table it does its stuff. The empTable contains more than 10k records so I am wondering if that will be an issue. When I ran the code on my table, it tried to return every employee with the data.

Comment: Ah, I missed the department. It will have to iterate Employee records anyway to group by their department, and get the nomination/submissions count, but I did goof on this. See my edit.

Comment: As to performance, this should be really quick if empowermentSubmissions.nomineeQID and empowermentSubmissions.locationID are paired in an index, and empowermentSubmissions.submitterQID and empowermentSubmissions.locationID are paired in an index. 10K records shouldn't be an issue.